# Limit persistent volume claim content folder size using hostPath

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volume-claims

I created a persistent volume claim with `20Mi storage limits` and `17 Mi storage requests` but I can upload a 50 Mi file in the `hostPath` folder. But what I want is to limit the folder content size. If the folder has more than 20Mi content in it so Kubernetes should say it does not allow new files.

Persistent volume:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: example-pv
  namespace: limit-range
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: local-storage
  hostPath:
    path: /home/me/kubernetes/web
    type: DirectoryOrCreate
```

Persistent volume claim:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
    name: pvc
    namespace: limit-range
spec:
    storageClassName: local-storage
    accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
    resources:
        limits:
            storage: 20Mi
        requests:
            storage: 17Mi
```

Deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: upload-preview-2
    namespace: limit-range
spec:
    selector:
        matchLabels:
            app: upload-preview-2
    template:
        metadata:
            labels:
                app: upload-preview-2
        spec:
            containers:
                - image: upload-preview:latest
                  imagePullPolicy: Never
                  name: web
                  ports:
                    - containerPort: 80
                  volumeMounts:
                    - mountPath: /var/www/html/web
                      name: localpath
                      subPath: dev

            volumes:
              - name: localpath
                persistentVolumeClaim:
                    claimName: pvc
```

With that configuration it does not give me what I expected. So I tried `Limit range` and `Quota` and still without the expected behavior.

Limit range:

```
apiVersion: v1 kind: LimitRange metadata:   name: storagelimits   namespace: limit-range spec:   limits:
  - type: PersistentVolumeClaim
    max:
      storage: 18Mi
    min:
      storage: 10Mi
```

Quota:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ResourceQuota
metadata:
  name: storagequota
  namespace: limit-range
spec:
  hard:
    persistentvolumeclaims: "5"
    requests.storage: "18Mi"
```

I tried `kubectl describe quota -n limit-range` and the result is:

```
Name:                   storagequota
Namespace:              limit-range
Resource                Used  Hard
--------                ----  ----
persistentvolumeclaims  1     5
requests.storage        17Mi  18Mi
```

My thought is maybe it does not work because I'm using `hostPath`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**There is no limit on how much space an emptyDir or hostPath volume can consume**, and no isolation between Containers or between Pods.

In the future, we expect that emptyDir and hostPath volumes will be able to request a certain amount of space using a resource specification, and to select the type of media to use, for clusters that have several media type.

[Official link for reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#resources)